# feof wrong loop in c

Tags: c, feof

I use below code to read a char from file and replace it with another,
but I have an error.loop in going to end of file.

What is wrong?

I tested this code on linux (netbeans IDE) and it was correct and worked beautiful but when I tried to use VS 2008 in windows , I found a non end loop.

```
//address = test.txt

FILE *fp;
fp=fopen(address,"r+");
if(fp == 0)
{
    printf("can not find!!");
}
else
{
    char w = '0';  /// EDIT : int w;
    while(1)
    {
        if((w = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        {
            if((w = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
            {
                fseek(fp,-2,SEEK_CUR);
                fprintf(fp,"0");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
} 
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Why don't you use *feof()* function instead of the *while(1)* loop>

Comment: That's interesting that this worked in Linux for you.  Maybe the type of (w = fgetc(f)) is ill defined when w is char?  Well investigate...

Comment: i tested it but it doesnot work too

Comment: if i use feof() in while then if i have 7 char i will have 8 at end;
if it is "123456" then the out put is  "0000000" it mean one char add to input.

Comment: it is int w ... iknow....i tested it with int but it does not worked

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with this loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [fopen documentation on cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/) says:

> For the modes where both read and
>   writing (or appending) are allowed
>   (those which include a "+" sign), the
>   stream should be flushed (fflush) or
>   repositioned (fseek, fsetpos, rewind)
>   between either a reading operation
>   followed by a writing operation or a
>   writing operation followed by a
>   reading operation.

We can add an `fflush` call after the `fprintf` to satisfy that requirement.

Here is my working code.  It creates a file named `example.txt` and after the program exits that file's contents will be `000000000000n`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE * fp;
    int w;

    fp = fopen("example.txt","w");
    fprintf(fp, "David Grayson");
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen("example.txt","r+");
    while(1)
    {
        if((w = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        {
            if((w = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
            {
                fseek(fp,-2,SEEK_CUR);
                fprintf(fp,"0");
                fflush(fp);  // Necessary!
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

This was tested with MinGW in Windows.

Answer (score 6):

You are storing the result of [`fgetc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgetc.html) in a char, instead of an int.

```
char w = '0'; /* Wrong, should be int. */
```

Incidentally, this problem is mentioned in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html).

> If type `char` is `unsigned`, an actual
>   EOF value will be truncated (by having
>   its higher-order bits discarded,
>   probably resulting in 255 or 0xff) and
>   will not be recognized as EOF,
>   **resulting in effectively infinite
>   input**.

**EDIT**

Reading your question again, it's highly fishy the way you seek back two characters and write one character. That could well lead to an infinite loop.

**EDIT2**

You (likely) want something like this (untested):

```
while ((w = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
    fprintf(fp, "0");
    fflush(fp); /* Apparently necessary, see the answer of David Grayson. */
}
```

Comment: yes you are correct...it is the problem.but what is solution?

Comment: i tested your edit2 and in this i have a non end loop , and when i break with ctrl+c and then open file with notepad i see milions of zero

Comment: @mimad You have to replace **your entire while** with that I posted.

Comment: yes ... i did it,,,,know the code is like below but does not work yet!
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(address,"r+");
    if(fp == 0)
    {
        printf("can not find!!");
    }
    else
    {
        int w = '0';  
        while ((w = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
  fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
  fprintf(fp, "0");
}

  fclose(fp);
    }

Comment: When switching between write and read you might need another fseek.

Comment: @Bo Persson  You are right.  You need an `fflush` or `fseek`.  See my answer.

Comment: EOF is defined to be -1 (at least in my environment) and a `char` can represent -1, so changing the `char` to an `int` should not affect the behavior of this program, assuming there are no -1 (0xFF) bytes in the input file.  See my answer for the real problem.

Comment: @David Grayson While this too is a problem, the char is a real issue :-) See the C FAQ.

Comment: Sure, it's real issue, but it wasn't causing the infinite loop, assuming the input file was ASCII and `char` is signed in the OP's compiler.  The C FAQ says: "The bug can go undetected for a long time, however, if chars are *signed* and if the input is all *7-bit characters*."

Comment: @David Grayson Fine :-) I myself don't like assuming much.